# PropertyGroup fails for a property which contains a path

Tags: msbuild

I've tried to refactor a build script and specify a path at one place, instead of copypasting it everywhere - however for some reason i can't seem to make my property work.

## myprops.props

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NetworkDeploymentRoot>\\FNFS-FS01\projects%24\company\product\deployment\mobile</NetworkDeploymentRoot>
        <XFVerbosity>0</XFVerbosity>
        <IsSymbolUploadSupported>0</IsSymbolUploadSupported>
        <IsSymbolUploadEnabled>1</IsSymbolUploadEnabled>
        <CopyToNetworkShare>0</CopyToNetworkShare>
        <GetAgentUploadConfirmation>0</GetAgentUploadConfirmation>
        <AgentConfirmedUpload>1</AgentConfirmedUpload>
        <CreateSvnBranch>0</CreateSvnBranch>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Ad-Hoc' ">
        <IsSymbolUploadEnabled>1</IsSymbolUploadEnabled>
        <CopyToNetworkShare>1</CopyToNetworkShare>
        <GetAgentUploadConfirmation>0</GetAgentUploadConfirmation>
        <AgentConfirmedUpload>1</AgentConfirmedUpload>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
        <IsSymbolUploadEnabled>1</IsSymbolUploadEnabled>
        <CopyToNetworkShare>1</CopyToNetworkShare>
        <GetAgentUploadConfirmation>0</GetAgentUploadConfirmation>
        <AgentConfirmedUpload>1</AgentConfirmedUpload>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'AppStore' ">
        <IsSymbolUploadEnabled>1</IsSymbolUploadEnabled>
        <CopyToNetworkShare>1</CopyToNetworkShare>
        <GetAgentUploadConfirmation>0</GetAgentUploadConfirmation>
        <AgentConfirmedUpload>1</AgentConfirmedUpload>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

## mytarget.targets

```
<Import Project="myprops.props" />

<Target Name="TestTarget3" AfterTargets="CopyIpaFromMac">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="AfterTarget CopyIpaFromMac" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Test: Dollar Configuration $(Configuration)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Test: Dollar CopyToNetworkShare $(CopyToNetworkShare)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Test: Dollar XFVerbosity $(XFVerbosity)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Test: Dollar NetworkDeploymentRoot $(NetworkDeploymentRoot)" />
    <Error Text="NetworkDeploymentRoot Property is not set" Condition="'$(NetworkDeploymentRoot)' == '' AND $(BuildIpa) == 'true'"/>
</Target>
```

All my flags properties work just fine - however the path always appears to be empty. Originally i had projects$ and figured i'd have to escape that, but that still didn't fix it.

Anyone got a clue why this does not seem to work for network share paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show works just fine, meaning that the problem is in code which you do not show: with the given code, the only way `$(NetworkDeploymentRoot)` can be empty in TestTarget3, is if some other target makes it empty. Tested this with multiple MsBuild versions just to make sure and indeed, after deleting the AfterTargets="CopyIpaFromMac" part, the output is always

```
>> msbuild mytarget.props /t:TestTarget3 /nologo
Build started 09-Feb-19 09:12:23.
Project "mytarget.props" on node 1 (TestTarget3 target(s)).
TestTarget3:
  AfterTarget CopyIpaFromMac
  Test: Dollar Configuration
  Test: Dollar CopyToNetworkShare 0
  Test: Dollar XFVerbosity 0
  Test: Dollar NetworkDeploymentRoot \\FNFS-FS01\projects$\company\product\deployment\mobile
Done Building Project "mytarget.props" (TestTarget3 target(s)).
```